# Flyway logs and schema_history_table show a repeatable migration was installed, but the database is not updated

Tags: flyway

We are using a dockerized version of Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 to manage db changes in a production environment. The database in question only has 2 versioned migrations and 3 repeatable migrations. Our most recent release included the introduction of the repeatable migrations (before this release all we has was 1 versioned migration). I noticed that the updates that the repeatable migrations were supposed to manage were not reflected in the database. The scripts are rather simple, just insert statements to add 3 new records to a table. The flyway logs show that the repeatable migrations were applied. The flyway_schema_history table also shows they were installed. I deleted the 3 records out of the flyway_schema_history table and re-ran flyway. The second time, the logs once again reported all the migrations were applied as did the flyway_schema_history table, but in reviewing the table in question only two of the scripts appear to have run. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Hi, just checking if I'm understanding. You have a repeatable migration, a `R__whatever.sql`, which adds 3 records to a table. When you run it the first time, those records are added, correct?
When you add a new version script and run flyway again, your expecting the repeatable to run again and add those 3 rows again, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: No. It never adds the 3 records. The flyway schema history table claims it did, but it did not.

Comment: what happens if you run manually your R__ migration script ?

Comment: The script runs successfully and the records are added.